# Javascript. Draggable div with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a draggable div, but I run into confusing behavior. The solution is copied from w3schools and it works correctly for them, but not for me. 
With a slight movement of the mouse, div always moves to the left, even if the mouse is moved up or down, and only with a large movement to the right, div follow the cursor.

div.js

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        x: this.props.x,
        y: this.props.y,
    }
    this.dragMouseDown = this.dragMouseDown.bind(this)
    this.elementDrag = this.elementDrag.bind(this)
    this.closeDragElement = this.closeDragElement.bind(this)
    this.reff = React.createRef()
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.pos1 = 0
    this.pos2 = 0
    this.pos3 = 0
    this.pos4 = 0
}

dragMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.pos3 = e.clientX
    this.pos4 = e.clientY
    document.onmouseup = this.closeDragElement
    document.onmousemove = this.elementDrag
}

elementDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.pos1 = this.pos3 - e.clientX
    this.pos2 = this.pos4 - e.clientY
    this.pos3 = e.clientX
    this.pos4 = e.clientY
    this.setState({
        y:(this.reff.current.offsetTop - this.pos2) + "px",
        x:(this.reff.current.offsetLeft - this.pos1) + "px",
    })
}

closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null
    document.onmousemove = null
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="tech row align-items-center justify-content-center border rounded"
             style={{left: this.state.x, top: this.state.y}}
             onMouseDown={this.dragMouseDown}
             ref={this.reff}
        >
                <img className="technology-icon" src={image} alt="technology_logo"></img>
                <span className="ml-1">{this.props.name}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Css with this div and container for it

```
.t_d{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
 .tech{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

And html for this (rows - an array of div components)

```
<div id="app"  style="height: 100%">
  <div className="fluid-container" style={{height: "100%"}}>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" id="nav">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>
    <div className="t_d">
            {rows}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, I tried to do something like the code below, and it works, but I don’t like the fact that the div is shifted to the cursor

```
this.setState({
        y: e.clientY - this.height + this.td.scrollTop + "px",
        x: e.clientX + this.td.scrollLeft + "px"
    })
```

Comment: I also saw this example on react. My problem was for a little drag the div goes out of screen scope (due to huge displacement)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a basic drag functionality in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077488/implementing-a-basic-drag-functionality-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the "row" class in "tech" div. Removed it and everything began to work as it should. Ha-ha.

```
<div className="tech border rounded"
```